# Find value for a function

Tags: linear-algebra, nonlinear-system

I have computed $\frac{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}}{\sqrt{x+y}} = k$ (Where $k$ is some scalar).

I want to find the value of the following function in terms of $k$ and $m$:

$\frac{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{my}}{\sqrt{x+my}}$ (Where $m$ is some scalar)

Please help if anyone can express the above function in terms of $k$ and $m$.

Answer (score 0):

Divide the numerator and denominator of both expressions by $\sqrt{y}$. This will result in
$$
k=\frac{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}}{\sqrt{x+y}}
=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{x}{y}} +1}{\sqrt{\frac{x}{y}+1}}
$$
and
$$
r=\frac{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{my}}{\sqrt{x+my}}
=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{x}{y}} +\sqrt{m}}{\sqrt{\frac{x}{y}+m}}
$$
You can use the first equation to obtain the ratio $\frac{x}{y}$ in terms of $k$ and insert this ratio into the second equation.